# Let $\phi:\Bbb Z_n\rightarrow G$ s.t. $\phi(i)=h^i$ for $0\le i\le n$. Give necessary and sufficient condition for $\phi$ to be homomorphism.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

The exercise reads

> Let $G$ be a group, $h$ and element of $G$, and $n$ a positive integer. Let $\phi : \mathbb{Z}_n\rightarrow G$ be defined by $\phi(i)=h^i$ for $0\leq i\leq n$. Give a necessary and sufficient condition (in terms of $h$ and $n$) for $\phi$ to be a homomorphism. Prove your assertion.

I always have problems with necessary and sufficient arguments, because I do not know how to prove. I know it implies an if and only if, but I'm not sure exactly over which is used. Now, if I look at the answer, it says:

> The map is a homomorphism if and only if  $h^n=e$, the identity in $G$.

But how do you know that I have to prove $h^n=e$?

I would have thought that I have to prove $\phi(n+m)=\phi(n)\phi(m)$, so it's quite confusing to think that we have to prove $h^n=e$.

Comment: You are using the letter $n$ in two different ways.

Comment: The question makes no sense. You say $\phi:\mathbb Z\to G$ is defined by $\phi(i)=h^i$ for $0\le i\le n$. What is $\phi(i)$ for other values of $i$?

Comment: Could it be that the question is asking about $\phi:\Bbb Z_n \to G$?

Comment: Missing an $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Then the reason is obvious. For $a,b=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, $\phi$ is obviously a homomorphism since $\phi(a+b)=\phi(a)\phi(b)$. The only thing left is to notice the value of $f(n)$. In $\Bbb Z_n$, $0$ and $n$ are congruent, so $f(n)=f(0)$ which gives $h^n=h^0=e$ which is the equivalent condition.

Comment: Obvious for you.

Comment: So maybe start by proving that $\tilde{\phi}: \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow G$, $i \mapsto h^i$ is always a homomorphism.

Comment: After that, think about a condition on $\tilde{\phi}$ that would allow you to  replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (hint: first isomorphism theorem).

Comment: @Timkinsella Please type up your hints as an answer in order to close the question. Until then (or whenever someone else decides to answer in greater detail), [this community wiki answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3049337/104041) referencing you will suffice :)

Answer (score 2):

*This community wiki answer is to point out that [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575989/group-homomorphism-necessary-and-sufficent-conditions-revisited?r=SearchResults#comment5316776_2575989) followed by [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575989/group-homomorphism-necessary-and-sufficent-conditions-revisited?r=SearchResults#comment5316783_2575989), both posted above by @Timkinsella (who is invited to post his own answer), form an answer to the question.*

*Summarising them:*

1) Prove $\tilde{\phi}: \Bbb Z\to G, i\mapsto h^i$ is always a homomorphism.

2) Think of the condition on $\tilde{\phi}$ that would allow $\Bbb Z$ to be replaced by $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$.

> **Hint:** First isomorphism theorem.